# Change the directory where VS 2017 Installer install packages

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio, xamarin, android-sdk-tools

I use both Xamarin and Java for android development. I want them use the same SDK to save disk space. By default, VS Installer install the android sdk in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, which contains whitespaces. Android studio cannot perform with sdks installed in whitespaced path, as it causes problems with Android NDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to move SDK to AS SDK folder. It's in C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.

In VS, you could open SDK manager in Tools->Android->Android SDK manager.
Then change the default folder.

[image]

Comment: When I open SDK manager, it popups Google's  android SDK manager, which the text of path is grey and I cannot modify it. Then I tried to install Xamarin SDK manager. In that I finally made it.

Comment: I also find another way. It's possible to change this in Tools>Options>Xamarin>Android Settings.